# Spectral gap vs. algebraic connectivity

Tags: graph-theory, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, definition, spectral-graph-theory

Can someone please clarify how the spectral gap of a graph relates to its algebraic connectivity (aka Fiedler value) and whether these use the adjacency matrix or laplacian matrix?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the distinct eigenvalues of the adjacency matrix of a $k$-regular graph are $k=\theta_1\ge\cdots\ge\theta_m$, the eigenvalues of its Laplacian 
in non-decreasing order are
\[
0, k-\theta_2,\ldots,k-\theta_m.
\]
So in this case the algebraic connectivity and the spectral gap coincide.

If the graph is not regular then, in general, there is no simple or useful relation between the eigenvalue of the adjacency matrix and the eigenvalues of the Laplacian.

Comment: Thanks. Do you know if something similar holds in an undirected weighted graphs when the sum of vertex weights of each node is equal?

Comment: The key point for regular graphs is that the diagonal matrix of valencies $D$ is a scalar times the identity. So if you can arrange your weights so the analogous matrix is scalar, you're OK. But arranging for the weighted matrix to be symmetric and to have constant row sums might not be easy.

Comment: Great - this can be achieved easily with Sinkhorn-Knopp balancing.